# How to read a LONGBLOB from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, groovy, casting, blob

I have a pdf stored in a database as a LONGBLOB.

I need to retrieve it binary output stream with a Groovy script.

I've tried this :

```
rowTest = sql.firstRow("select data from mytable id = 666");
file = rowTest[0];
myLongBlob = (oracle.sql.BLOB)file;
```

However, I get a cast exception :

```
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[B@48eb2326' with class '[B' to class 'oracle.sql.BLOB'
```

Then I realized I was trying to cast a LONGBLOB to a BLOB which is probably the reason why this error happens ?

Anyway, is there another way to read my PDF from a LONGBLOB ?

Thanks.

Edit : The error is not due to casting a LONGBLOB to BLOB, I tried with a BLOB and same error happens.

Edit : I'm trying to follow this tutorial : http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+from+a+Blob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object `'[B@48eb2326'` refers to a byte array; the object at `rowTest[0]` is a `byte[]`, not a `Blob`. So the easiest thing would probably be `byte[] myLongBlob = (byte[]) file` (which is probably more convenient for you to work with, anyway!).

Comment: Right, but I'm refering to this tutorial : http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+from+a+Blob and they seem to cast directly rowTest[0] to BLOB

My goal is to get a BLOB object so I can use the getBinaryOutputStream() method.

Comment: It's probably specific to the JDBC driver. The tutorial assumes an Oracle database; are you using MySQL, Postgres or some other database? That could well be the difference. In any regard, I would trust your JVM over online documentation. :) The object _is_ a `byte[]`, regardless of what the tutorial says it should be. Do you need it as a `Blob` object?

Comment: I'm using MySQL.

And I'm trying to read a PDF from a database stored as a LONGBLOB, so I was trying to cast it to a BLOB to get it binary stream using oracle.sql.BLOB.getBinaryStream() so I could pass it binary data to a web application and see the PDF online.

Comment: MySQL is returning it as a `byte[]` it would seem. If you need it as an `InputStream`, you can wrap it in `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Comment: Seems to be a good idea, shouldnt be hard to transform back to PDF then. Thanks