# How to Display an Image in PDF, which is retrieved from MySql Database using JSP and iText

Tags: mysql, jsp, pdf, itext

I want to generate a PDF with **iText** and **Servlet injsp**, which will show the records stored in a **mysql** database of type **Blob(Image)**. But its not being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to insert image to the pdf from mysql
 [View this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/image.html) [View this](http://binodsuman.blogspot.in/2009/04/how-to-insert-image-in-pdf-using-itext.html)
this gives you idea...

```
public void createPDF(){

Document d = new Document (PageSize.A4);
try {
PdfWriter.getInstance(d, new FileOutputStream("sample.pdf"));
d.open ();
d.addCreator("Sample Demo.java");
d.addAuthor("Sundar");
d.addTitle("First PDF By Sundar");
//this is where you have to do your query to fetch image as BLOB from DB
//Blob imageBlob = resultSet.getBlob(yourBlobColumnIndex);
//byte[] imageBytes = imageBlob.getBytes(1, (int) imageBlob.length());
Image image = Image.getInstance(imageBytes);
image.scaleAbsolute(300,300);
d.add(image);
d.close ();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} 
System.out.println("******** PDF Created ***************");

}
```

Comment: Sundar, its fine whose link u send me, but its not showing the method to retrieve image from mysql database, its just an example of Image class

Comment: Sundar, thank u Very much yar, u have helped me a lot..
 Actually the problem was in data type,the db contain longblob, but i was using blob, i think that was a great problem. when i change the database having table with blob type it worked.

Can you give me another suggestion, how to do this with longblob or mediumblob??

Plz... :)

Comment: Sundar, Plz help me regarding my another question i.e, this code works for Blob Type, but what to do if we have used mediumblob or longblob. This code doesn't work in that case

Comment: view this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164860/how-to-read-a-longblob-from-mysql

Comment: Its work like a Charm. We need to take care while importin "Image". which must be associated with com.itextpdf.text.Image. Don,t import Image from sql or any other class.